# How to link register-login script in php to my html file?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a **login-register script** forked from here - 
https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal

I have my website coded in **bootstrap** as a css framework and everything is in **html**. My index file is also html. Also I have a **Popup-Login snippet** from over here - http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/sign-in-sign-up-dual-modal

Now if I want to **include** php files into html it is considered as a bad practice and moreover **Netbeans(IDE)** doesn't allow you to write php code into html once you have created a **HTML project**. *Edit*:Do I need to have my index file containing the form in php to get this working?

How should I proceed? How should I link the php stuff to my **popup form fields** and get this combination to work? I was unable to find any answers on the net anywhere.

Comment: It's not considered as bad practice, but you can instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP. Otherwise, use `.php` as an extension for all your files.

Comment: Yes that was my last resort. But isn't there anything else that can work?

Comment: you can use SSI `.shtml` extension and include `.php` files if your server allows it; I do it myself. Other than that, you can try using an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `.html` files are treated as static, and so the PHP code inside will not get executed. Moreover, it will be visible in the source of a page (when you click View->Source). It must not what you want to do ;)

I suggest you write a separate `.php` file with your PHP code, and then include the HTML code where you need it. Not the other way around!

Comment: Yes indeed! It works when you create a php file and include html into it. I managed to register and login by including the required file. Thanks